# Call WooCommerce 2.1 REST APT in Ionic Framework using Ouath1.a

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, woocommerce, phonegap-plugins

I want to call WooCommerce 2.1 REST APT in my ionic mobile app using Ouath1.0a protocol.

For example :

```
 http://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/products?
```

To call this service we required parameters like

```
 oauth_consumer_key 
 oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
 oauth_timestamp= xxxxxxxxxx
 oauth_nonce= xxxxxx
 oauth_version=1.0
 oauth_signature= ??????
```

Now I am facing problem how to create **oauth_signature** in ionic & angular js.

I refer the [link 1](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/understanding-request-signing-oauth-1-0a-providers/) & [link2](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I got the solution with the help of this [issue](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/7460).

Solution are as follows :

We required the some dependency to implement this like as follows,

1. hmac-sha1
2. enc-base64
3. oauth-1.0a
4. oauth-signature

Download the js files and place in your required directory and include in your index.html

Here I am Creating  the service in angularjs to handle the calling of woocommerce api ,

```
            angular.module('myapp.restservices', [])
            .service("serverRepo",['$q','$http','errorHandler','$ionicLoading',function($q,$http,errorHandler,$ionicLoading){
                var self=this;
                 //Request Url and method
                var request = {
                        url: 'http://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/products',
                        method: 'GET'
                };  
                //OAuth Protocol authentication parameters
                var oauth = new OAuth({
                        consumer: {
                            //Consumer Public Key
                            public: 'ck_50xxxx',
                            //Consumer Secrete Key
                            secret: 'cs_b4xxxx'
                        },
                        //oauth1.0a protocol signature method
                        signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
                });

                //Service Function to get products
                this.products=function(){
                     $ionicLoading.show({
                            template: '<ion-spinner class="light"></ion-spinner>'
                     });
                     //OAuth Parameters to call woocommerce api
                    var oauth_data = {
                        oauth_consumer_key: oauth.consumer.public,
                        oauth_nonce: oauth.getNonce(),
                        oauth_signature_method: oauth.signature_method,
                        oauth_timestamp: oauth.getTimeStamp()
                    };
                    //Oauth signature
                    oauth_data.oauth_signature = oauthSignature.generate(request.method,request.url,oauth_data,oauth.consumer.secret );
                    console.log("Params : "+ JSON.stringify(oauth_data));
                    var deff=$q.defer();
                    $http({
                        method:"GET",
                        url:request.url,
                        headers: {
                                    "Content-Type":"application/JSON",
                                },
                        params: oauth_data
                        }).then(function(objS){
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            alert('Success :-    '+JSON.stringify(objS));
                        },function(objE){
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            alert('error:-    '+JSON.stringify(objE));
                            errorHandler.serverErrorhandler(objE);
                            deff.reject("server Error");
                        });
                        return deff.promise;
                    };
                }])
                .service('errorHandler',['$q',function($q){
                    this.serverErrorhandler=function(error){
                        alert("ERROR ::"+JSON.stringify(error));
                        console.log("ERROR ::"+JSON.stringify(error));
                    };
                 }
            ])
```

Write controller to call the service function as like follows,

```
    angular.module(myapp.categorycontrollers, [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,woocommerce) {
            //Method to get all Products
              $scope.getAllProducts = function(){
                    woocommerce.products().then(function(objS){
                     },function(err){
                    });
              }
             //calling to function
              $scope.getAllProducts();
     }
```

For more help go to [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2016/03/woocommerce-rest-api-with-ionic.html).